# earphones mic doesnt work when plugged into audio jack

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

For some reason, when I plug my earphones into my phone, the mic works, but when I plug it into my laptop, it doesn't work. I have tried:

- installing, reinstalling and updating drivers
- allowing apps mic access in privacy settings
- fiddling with sound settings
- downloading realtek audio manager, but for whatever reason it never appeared in control panel
- downloading dell audio manger/console yet, same thing, never appeared in control panel

I'm certain it's a TRRS earphone jack plugged into mic/headset combo socket, so I don't get why it wouldn't work. Here are pictures of my earphones pin and input socket if you're curious.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The socket doesn't look correctly lined up to the case moulding.

I see two possible fixes, one simpler then the other.

1. Trim the jack with a modelling knife to gain a bit more depth out of it…
   [image]

if still no joy…

2. take the case apart & see what's preventing it lining up properly. You may find a surface-mount component which has been banged/knocked & damaged one of the contacts to the circuit board.